# Django - Url dispatch No match from application

Tags: regex, django, django-urls

I have a simple url that doesn't match into one of my applications (**plaq**)

**main url.py:**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
  #...
  url(r'^content/', include('content.urls')),
  url(r'^$', include('content.urls')),
  url(r'^plaq/', include('plaq.urls')),
  #...
)
```

**plaq url.py:**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
  (r'^$', pres),
  (r'pres^$', pres),
  (r'about^$', about),
  (r'privacy^$', privacy),
)
```

Trying to access to `my_host/plaq/pres` gives me

> Using the URLconf defined in my_project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
>   ...
>   12. ^content/
>   13. ^plaq/ ^$
>   14. ^plaq/ pres^$
>   15. ^plaq/ about^$
>   16. ^plaq/ privacy^$
>   ...
>   The current URL, plaq/pres/, didn't match any of these.

While `my_host/plaq` displays the good `pres` view

Why can't I access to `my_host/plaq/pres` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you need to learn a bit about regexes: `^` means beginning of string, but for some reason you have it at the end.

Secondly, your URLs end in slashes, so your urlconfs must too.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
  (r'^$', pres),
  (r'^pres/$', pres),
  (r'^about/$', about),
  (r'^privacy/$', privacy),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

carets (`^`) match the beginning of a string. i think you want e.g. `(r'^pres$', pres),` (caret moved to front)